# How effective is the Intel video Frame Buffer core when storing in memory?

Tags: intel-fpga, video

The Intel Video and Image Processing (VIP) Suite IP has a Video Frame Buffer (VFB) core, named Frame Buffer II IP Core, that can take streaming images on the Avalon-ST IF and save them into memory using Avalon-MM IF, for using a DDR3 memory controller.

In my application, the VFB Frame Buffer II IP Core has these interfaces:

- Streaming video: Avalon-ST IF width 48 bits (for 2 pixels in parallel of 24 bits each)
- Memory interface: Avalon-MM IF width 64 bits

Since the memory bandwidth is critical, I want to determine the expected amount of overhead, but I am unable to find any information about this in the "Video and Image Processing Suite User Guide (UG-VIPSUITE | 2021.02.12)".

So, how effectively does the VFB Frame Buffer II IP Core pack the 48-bit Avalon-ST IF data into the memory using the 64-bit Avalon-MM IF?  For example, is the 48-bit Avalon-ST data packed back-to-back in memory, or is the 48-bit Avalon-ST data aligned to the 64-bit Avalon-MM data size, thereby introducing an overhead of 33%?.

Comment: @ocrdu: Thanks for the corrections; I am not a native English speaker, so I appreciate the fixes.

Comment: Got a close vote with reason: "Questions on the use of electronic devices are off-topic as this site is intended specifically for questions on electronics design."  However, this question is indeed about design, since the Video and Image Processing (VIP) Suite IP is used to design new equipment; there is actually no other use of it.  Please make a comment with specific reason, if there is still an opinion that I should modify or delete this question.

Comment: Yet another close vote, with same reason, but still no comment... How can I then learn or improve... or are the down-voters simply being malicious to this forum while hiding in their anonymity?

Comment: The VIP Suite comes with extensive documentation that covers your question. You need to give more details about how that documentation is failing to address your specific concern.

Comment: The last version of the VIP Suite User Guide that I downloaded was the 2018.09.24 version. Your question is answered in section 16.7.3, "Memory Map for Frame Reader or Writer Configurations".

Comment: @DaveTweed: Thanks a lot for pointing to section "16.7.3. Memory Map for Frame Reader or Writer Configurations".  I had searched through the chapter "16. Frame Buffer II IP Core", but missed out the importance of that section.  Think this paragraph is the major point: "The frame data is tightly packed into memory and aligned on frame (or field) boundaries to minimize storage usage and maximize memory bandwidth usage.".  If you make a regular answer, I will mark this as the answer, and otherwise I will make an answer myself in a couple of days.

Comment: @DaveTweed: A related question, do you know where I can find a description of the Avalon-ST video protocol, since I have to write a module that interfaces to other VIP suite module modules (cores) ?  Any help is greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: Chapter 2 of that same document. I do most of my module development using the AXI-4 sreaming interface that Xilinx uses, and I wrote a couple of adapter "shim" modules that allow me to convert between Avalon-ST video and AXI-4 streaming video. There are just minor differences in the handshaking (READY/VALID) and significant differences in how the frame geometry is processed -- Avalon uses control packets, AXI-4 uses TUSER/TLAST.

Comment: @DaveTweed: Thanks a lot for the comment, and I will look further on that.  Btw. your comment yesterday was a great help, so I now expect to have a nice solution to a development problem I have been looking at for some time.  So again, thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments from Dave Tweed, the answer can be found in documentation from Intel in document ["Video and Image Processing Suite User Guide"](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/programmable/us/en/pdfs/literature/ug/ug_vip.pdf).  In revision 2021.02.12 the relevant section is "16.7.3. Memory Map for Frame Reader or Writer Configurations", where a paragraph says:

> The frame data is tightly packed into memory and aligned on frame (or field)
> boundaries to minimize storage usage and maximize memory bandwidth usage.

Figure "Figure 69. Memory Map for Base Address 0x1000_0000 for Non 8-Bit Pixel Values" also shows dense packing of some less-typical bit formats.

General information about video flow in Avalon-ST packets can be found in section "2.2. Avalon-ST Video Packet Types".